# Cell enter - Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

`Cell enter - Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function` this error will appear if i do this:

```
Private Sub dg1_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg1.CellEnter
 if e.columnindex = 4
  if dg1.CurrentRow.Cells("id").Value = 0
   dg1.endEdit(true)
   msgbox("choose any item in cell3 before you can proceed here")
   dg1.CurrentCell = dg1.CurrentRow.Cells(3)
   exit sub
  end
   'my code here . . .
 end if
End Sub
```

I just want to stop the user entering or executing my code in `cell 4` if she/he
did not select any items in `cell 3`

When user select an item in `cell 3` the `cells("id")` will have a value depends on the id of `cell 3` value. but error always shown up when i click `cell 4`.

anyone can solve this? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you got reentrant exception is that setting the current cell will force the CellEnter event to be triggered. To avoid this exception, please add this into your code:

`Delegate Sub SetColumnIndex(ByVal i As Integer)`

```
Private Sub Mymethod(ByVal columnIndex As Integer)
    dg1.CurrentCell = dg1.CurrentRow.Cells(columnIndex)
End Sub
```

then in your code:

```
if dg1.CurrentRow.Cells("id").Value = 0
   msgbox("choose any item in cell3 before you can proceed here")
   Dim method As New SetColumnIndex(AddressOf Mymethod)
   dg1.BeginInvoke(method, 3)
   Exit Sub
end if
```

if this doesn't work just inform me.